# Python printing output to file adds extra blank line

Tags: python, file, replace

I'm writing a simple program that replaces one word of a text file with the word "banana." Here is how it is currently structured:

```
file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Users/Alex/Desktop", title="Open File", filetypes=(("TXT files", "*.txt"), ))
for line in fileinput.FileInput(file,inplace=1):
    if 'sports' in line:
        temp = line.split()
        rep = temp[0]
        line = line.replace(rep, "Banana")
    print(line)
```

The word is replaced as intended, however whenever I check the new file, there is a blank line between each line of text. It should look like this:

```
Cats are cute.
Banana enjoy sports.
I like to wear jackets.
Green is my favorite color.
```

But instead, it looks like this:

```
Cats are cute.

Banana enjoy sports.

I like to wear jackets.

Green is my favorite color.
```

How can I get rid of the blank line between each line of text in the file?

Answer (score 1):

The `print()` function adds a newline at the end of the print statement per default. If you want to get rid of it, pass an empty string as the third parameter. For more information, see the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp

Answer (score 0):

When iterating a file (or file-like object), each line ends with a newline `\n`.

So you need to strip it since the `print` function will add another `\n`:

```py
for line in fileinput.FileInput(file, inplace=1):
    line = line.rstrip()  # drop newline
    if "sports" in line:
        temp = line.split()
        rep = temp[0]
        line = line.replace(rep, "Banana")
    print(line)
```

You can also tell `print` not to print a newline, using `end` keyword argument:

```py
for line in fileinput.FileInput(file, inplace=1):
    if "sports" in line:
        temp = line.split()
        rep = temp[0]
        line = line.replace(rep, "Banana")
    print(line, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `print` adds an extra newline after whatever you pass it.  You can change this with

```
print(line, end='')
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print